# Where to get DSOleFile.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I am trying to get a legacy vb.net application up and running and I need DSOleFile.dll. Does anyone know where this file can be downloaded and what it does?

Answer (score 0):

This link was inside the top entry in a Google search for "DSOLeFile.dll"... 
[Setup for DSOLeFile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351)

Comment: Did that answer your question?